# mysqlslap chokes on strings that contain ";" delimiter?

Tags: mysql, mysqlslap

I'm having a problem passing preexisting files full of SQL statements into mysqlslap.

For example, I have a file named `create.sql` that contains my table structure (as dumped by `mysqldump`), with normal ; delimiting.

I also have a file called `slap.sql` (actually a slightly munged [general-log-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file), but this is a tiny example that reproduces the error) that contains

```
INSERT INTO comments VALUES ("I like winks ;) and frowns :(");
```

And I run:

```
mysqlslap --delimiter=";" --create create.sql --query thing.sql
```

I get the error:

```
mysqlslap: Cannot run query INSERT INTO comments VALUES ("I like winks  
ERROR : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"I like winks' at line 1
```

Which is consistent with MySQL terminating the statement at the ; that's in the *middle of a string*.

What can I do to make mysqlslap take `--create` data from mysqldump and not hork on semicolons embedded in strings in the `--query` data?  Is it possible that mysqlslap does not follow normal parsing rules when you pass a file in to the --query parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it up.  Because (as Michael pointed out) mysqlslap is using naive string finding instead of a parser for the delimiter, if the delimiter you pick is anywhere in your --query or --create datasets, you're hosed.

Instead, open up the mysqldump file, and merge any multiline statements into one line and let mysqlslap continue to expect one-statement-per-line.

If you use Vim it's dead easy, just search for known multiline patterns (in mine it was only CREATE TABLE, I guess it might include stored procedures or triggers), then use `J` to join up all the lines in each statement.

Answer (score 3):

Looking briefly at the source code, it looks like mysqlslap doesn't do any sophisticated parsing for delimiters... it's just splitting strings.

If you write each of your queries on a single line, you don't have to terminate them -- the default statement delimiter is a newline.

```
const char *delimiter= "\n";
```

With one query per line, it splits the line and executes each statement.

The `;` delimiter isn't actually needed at the end of each query to make the `--query` file valid and the server has no problem executing the example query you provided with the semicolon removed.

You could modify the output file from `mysqldump` to use a different delimiter, like `$$`, using `sed` or `perl` and then use that delimiter in your query file also.

```
mysqldump [args] | perl -pe 's/;$/\n\$\$\n/g' > create.sql
```

---

edit: oops, yeah, this is *really* primitive... multi-<strike>character</strike>byte delimiters aren't really even supported.

```
if (user_supplied_query)
    actual_queries= parse_delimiter(tmp_string, &query_statements, delimiter[0]);
```

Comment: I really like the idea of changing the delimiter, but the crux of the problem seems to be that it has to be one character (2 char delimiters behaved incomprehensibly) and if that one char is in your data, you're boned.  (I also couldn't get exotic unicode that I knew wasn't in my dataset to work.)